# How do you find what week in a month a day is on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to wrap my head around what might be an easy question..

Suppose I have the date..

```
Fri, 14 Sep 2012 18:37:50 +0200
```

How do I find out what week this date is on for this month? Is it the 1st, the 2nd..? The third?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you considering the 1st to 7th day of the month the first week? The 8th to 14th day of the week the second month? Etc?

Comment: If the 1st is a Thursday, what week is Monday 5th?

Comment: @JustinKo No, that wouldn't be correct. Because sometimes the 2nd is on the 2nd week. Gareth, that would be the 2nd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sachin87 has a [library](https://github.com/sachin87/week-of-month) for determining such a thing.

Comment: The week_in_month gem makes the assumption your weeks start on Sunday, which is generally only US and Canada. There's no configuration I could see for a first-day-monday option.

Comment: @Beejamin `WeekOfMonth.configuration.monday_active = true` was probably added after you wrote this comment.

Answer (score 11):

Why use a library?  Ruby has it by default:

```
Week number:
The week 1 of YYYY starts with a Sunday or Monday (according to %U
  or %W).  The days in the year before the first week are in week 0.
    %U - Week number of the year.  The week starts with Sunday.  (00..53)
    %W - Week number of the year.  The week starts with Monday.  (00..53)

> Time.zone.parse("2012-01-01").strftime("%U")
=> "01"
```

So, given that we can find what week a given date is in the year, we can do some math to figure out what week of the month it occurs in.

```
> week_of_year_for_first_of_month = Time.zone.parse("2012-07-01").strftime("%U").to_i
> week_of_target_date = Time.zone.parse("2012-07-14").strftime("%U").to_i
> week_occurs_in = week_of_target_date - week_of_year_for_first_of_month + 1
> week_occurs_in # => 2
```

Or a method:

```
def week_of_month_for_date(date)
  my_date = Time.zone.parse(date)
  week_of_target_date = my_date.strftime("%U").to_i
  week_of_beginning_of_month = my_date.beginning_of_month.strftime("%U").to_i
  week_of_target_date - week_of_beginning_of_month + 1
end

> week_of_month_for_date("2012-07-14") # => 2 
> week_of_month_for_date("2012-07-15") # => 3
```

Comment: Nice... but the OP wants the week *of the month*, not of the year.

Comment: Wow awesome. I could see that coming in handy. I would *love* to see that for week of the month though.

Comment: Updated to solve problem of OP.  That being said, the week_of_month gem by sachin87 looks pretty cool.

Comment: Depending on your use case you may want to take @Kelvin's advice in account. This code only isn't enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

Note that it depends how you count weeks. Let's say June 1 is on a Saturday. What week do you consider June 2 to be on? It might be the second week, or maybe it's the first if you consider a countable week to contain at least 4 days.

Or perhaps, given that June 2 is a Sunday, what's the week number of that Sunday? It's unambiguously the first Sunday. If this is what you mean, then it's actually simple. Dates 1 through 7 are always the first [weekday name] in the month. Dates 8-14 are always second. And so on. All you have to do is build a hash, and it will work for any month.

Comment: This is a very important point, absolutely. Also if you are working recurring schedules, and you would like something to appear on the fifth week, the following month may not have a fifth week.

Comment: This is an important point. Often, Americans tend to ignore the international standards (like the metric system, not to say, or ISO 8601 in this case), and go their own way. And yes, Kelvin is even better than Celsius.

Answer (score 2):

The [week_of_month](https://github.com/sachin87/week-of-month) gem looks like it might be a bit overkill. That implementation uses a lot of array splitting and `Array.include?` checks.

Instead, here's a module that you can mixin to `Date` and `Time` to get the desired behavior.

```
require "active_support/core_ext/date"
require "active_support/core_ext/time"

module WeekCalculator
  def week_of_year(mondays = false)
    # Use %U for weeks starting on Sunday
    # Use %W for weeks starting on Monday
    strftime(mondays ? "%W" : "%U").to_i + 1
  end

  def week_of_month(mondays = false)
    week_of_year(mondays) - beginning_of_month.week_of_year(mondays) + 1
  end
end

class Date
  include WeekCalculator
end

class Time
  include WeekCalculator
end
```

---

```
Date.new(2014, 1, 1).week_of_year            # => 1
Date.new(2014, 1, 1).week_of_month           # => 1
Date.new(2014, 7, 1).week_of_year            # => 27
Date.new(2014, 7, 1).week_of_month           # => 1

Date.new(2014, 7, 27).week_of_year           # => 31
Date.new(2014, 7, 27).week_of_month          # => 5
Date.new(2014, 7, 27).week_of_year(:monday)  # => 30
Date.new(2014, 7, 27).week_of_month(:monday) # => 4
```

Comment: week_of_month gem is roughly the same speed (2sec difference on a large data set on badass ssd computer with i7) but yours is faster.

Answer (score 1):

I was challenged with answering "June 30th, 2017 is the **nth** Friday in June, 2017".

I solved this by building an array of all of the day names (Monday, Tuesday, etc) accrued up until the target date, and counting how many matched.

```
target_date = Date.new(2017, 6, 30)
(1..target_date.day).select do |day_of_month|
  Date.new(target_date.year, target_date.month, day_of_month).strftime('%A') == target_date.strftime('%A')
end.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, find the week of a_date (considering first week is 1, and first day of week is monday):

```
week = (((a_date.mday + Date.new(a_date.year, a_date.month, 1).wday - 1) / 7) + 1)
```